# Веса нейронных сетей

Tags: нейронные-сети

При корректировании весов в нейронной сети, один из весов стал минусовый . Использую функцию активации логистической функции.Могут ли веса в нейронных сетях быть минусовыми ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Часто под логистической функцией подразумевают [сигмоиду](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0), если это так, тогда ответ - да, веса могут быть отрицательными. Если взвешенная сумма весов - 0, тогда сигмоида будет равна 0,5, соответственно при плюсовой взвешенной сумме сигмоида будет стремиться к единице, при отрицательной - к нулю.